¿No logro mostrar los datos de mi base de datos en una tabla(tree)
En los módulos a continuación, funciona muy bien cuando registro datos a la base de datos(mongodb). Sin embargo, cuando intento incluir los documentos de la base de datos(mongodb) a una tabla(tree), realizo el módulo mostrar_paciente, todo se vuelve un caos, sale infinitas errores, modifico y por cualquier razón arroja el siguiente error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\USER\Documents\Software\SoftwareOdontologico\index.py", line 1, in 
from ventanas.manager import Manager
File "c:\Users\USER\Documents\Software\SoftwareOdontologico\ventanas\manager.py", line 3, in 
from ventanas.container import Container
File "c:\Users\USER\Documents\Software\SoftwareOdontologico\ventanas\container.py", line 3, in 
from ventanas.paciente import Paciente
File "c:\Users\USER\Documents\Software\SoftwareOdontologico\ventanas\paciente.py", line 5, in 
import funcion.mostrar_paciente as mp
File "c:\Users\USER\Documents\Software\SoftwareOdontologico\funcion\mostrar_paciente.py", line 10
tree.insert('',0,text=document["_id"], values=document["primerApe"], values=document["segundoApe"])                                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated: values
La verdad no sé que hago mal. Solicito una manito amiga, pues estoy aprendiendo. Gracias
index.py
from manager import Manager
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Manager()
    app.mainloop()

mananger.py
from tkinter import Tk, Frame
from ttkthemes import ThemedStyle
from container import Container

class Manager(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Software Odontológico")
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.configure(bg="#2b4051")
        self.geometry("800x400+120+120")

        self.container = Frame(self, bg="#2b4051")
        self.container.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.frames={
            Container: None
        }

        self.load_frame()
        self.show_frame(Container)
        self.set_theme()

def load_frame(self):
    for FrameClass in self.frames.keys():
        frame = FrameClass(self.container, self)
        self.frames[FrameClass] = frame

def show_frame(self, frame_class):
    frame = self.frames[frame_class]
    frame.tkraise()

def set_theme(self):
    style = ThemedStyle(self)
    style.set_theme("adapta")

def main():
    app = Manager
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()

paciente.py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
import crear_registro as cr
import mostrar_paciente as mp

class Paciente(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.widgets()

    def widgets(self):
        frame1 = tk.Frame(self, bg="#009587", highlightbackground="gray", highlightthickness=1)
        frame1.pack()
        frame1.place(x=0, y=0, width=1100, height=100)

        titulo = tk.Label(self, text="Pacientes", bg="#009587", font="sans 30 bold", anchor="center",fg="white")
        titulo.pack()
        titulo.place(x=5, y=0, width=1090, height=90)
    
        frame2 = tk.Frame(self, bg="white",highlightbackground="gray", highlightthickness=1)
        frame2.place(x=0, y= 100, width=1100, height=550)

        lblframe = LabelFrame(frame2, text= "Información del Paciente", bg="white", font="sans 12 bold",fg=("#009587"))
        lblframe.place(x=10, y=10, width=1060, height=80)

        label_num_historia = tk.Label(lblframe, text=("Historia N°"), fg=("#009587"), font="sans 11 bold")
        label_num_historia.place(x=10, y=10)
        self.num_historia = tk.StringVar()
        self.entryNumHistoria = ttk. Entry(lblframe, textvariable= self.num_historia, state= "readonly", font="sans 11 bold")
        self.entryNumHistoria.place(x=100, y=10, width=80)

        label_num_historia = tk.Label(lblframe, text=("Cédula N°"), fg=("#009587"), font="sans 11 bold")
        label_num_historia.place(x=200, y=10)
        self.entryCedula = ttk. Entry(lblframe,  font="sans 11")
        self.entryCedula.place(x=285, y=10)

        label_primerApe = tk.Label(lblframe, text=("Primer \nApellido"), fg=("#009587"), font="sans 11 bold")
        label_primerApe.place(x=470, y=0)
        self.entry_primerApe = ttk. Entry(lblframe, font="sans 11")
        self.entry_primerApe.place(x=560, y=10)
    
        label_segundoApe = tk.Label(lblframe, text=("Segundo \nApellido"), fg=("#009587"), font="sans 11 bold")
        label_segundoApe.place(x=770, y=0)
        self.entry_segundoApe = ttk. Entry(lblframe, font="sans 11")
        self.entry_segundoApe.place(x=860, y=10)

        treFrame = tk.Frame(frame2, bg=("#009587"))
        treFrame.place(x=150, y=120, width=800, height= 200)

        scrol_y = ttk.Scrollbar(treFrame, orient= VERTICAL)
        scrol_y.pack(side= RIGHT, fill= Y)
        scrol_x = ttk.Scrollbar(treFrame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        scrol_x.pack(side= BOTTOM, fill= X)

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(treFrame, columns=("Cédula", "Primer Apellido", "Segundo Apellido", "Nombres"), show="headings", 
                             height=10, yscrollcommand=scrol_y.set,xscrollcommand=scrol_x.set)
    
        scrol_y.config(command=self.tree.yview)
        scrol_x.config(command=self.tree.xview)

        self.tree.heading("#1", text="Cédula")
        self.tree.heading("#2", text="Primer Apellido")
        self.tree.heading("#3", text="Segundo Apellido")
        self.tree.heading("#4", text="Nombres")

        self.tree.column("Cédula", anchor="center")
        self.tree.column("Primer Apellido", anchor="center")
        self.tree.column("Segundo Apellido", anchor="center")
        self.tree.column("Nombres", anchor="center")

        self.tree.pack(expand= True, fill=BOTH)

        lblframe1 = LabelFrame(frame2, text="Opciones",bg="white", font="sans 12 bold",fg=("#009587"))
        lblframe1.place(x=10, y=380, width=1060, height=100)

       boton_agregar = tk.Button(lblframe1, text="Agregar Paciente", bg= "#009587", fg="white", font="sans 14 bold",  
                              command=lambda: cr.nuevoPaciente(
                                  self.entryCedula.get(),
                                  self.entry_primerApe.get(), 
                                  self.entry_segundoApe.get()))
       boton_agregar.place(x=50, y=10, width=240, height=50)

       boton_buscar = tk.Button(lblframe1, text="Buscar Paciente", bg= "#009587", fg="white", font="sans 14 bold",  
                              )
                                
       boton_buscar.place(x=350, y=10, width=240, height=50)
  
cargarDatos()

crear_registro.py
from database import get_paciente_collection

    def nuevoPaciente(
           entry_cedula, 
           entry_primerApe, 
           entry_segundoApe
           ):

        documents = {
            '_id': entry_cedula,
            'primerApe': entry_primerApe,
            'segundoApe': entry_segundoApe
        }
        with get_paciente_collection() as collection:
            collection.insert_one(documents)


    print(documents)

mostrar_paciente.py
from database import get_paciente_collection
import pymongo

def mostrarDatos(tree):
    with get_paciente_collection() as collection:
    
        documents = tree.get_children()
        for document in documents:
            tree.delete(document)
        for document in collection.find():
            tree.insert('',0,text=document["_id"], values=document["primerApe"], values=document["segundoApe"])
print(document)  

database.py
from contextlib import contextmanager
from pymongo import MongoClient

@contextmanager
def get_paciente_collection():
    client = None
    try:
        client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
        base_datos = client["odontoBd"] #nombre base de datos
        collection = base_datos["paciente"] #Se crea la coleccion
        yield collection
    except Exception as ex:
        print(f"Error de conexión a la base de datos: {ex}")
    finally:
        if client is not None:
            client.close()


El problema lo tienes en mostrar_paciente.py en la linea:
tree.insert('',0,text=document["_id"], values=document["primerApe"], values=document["segundoApe"])
                                       ^^^^^^                        ^^^^^^
                                       |    |                        |    |

Como el propio error indica estás usando el argumento por palabra clave values de Treeview.insert() dos veces al llamarlo.
Al argumento values le tienes que pasar un iterable con los valores de las columnas de la segunda en adelante (la primera columna es la #0 y su valor es el pasado mediante el argumento text). Por lo tanto, pasa una lista o tupla con todos los valores para la fila a insertar, algo como:
tree.insert('', 0, values=(document["_id"], document["primerApe"], document["segundoApe"]))

Obviamente el orden/indice de los items del iterable debe corresponderse con el de sus respectivas columnas.
Ten en cuenta que estás usando el modo headings del Treeview (show="headings"), por lo que la primera columna no se visualizará y lo que le pases al argumento text de insert no se mostrará.

Gracias FJSevila, muy agradecido por su gran colaboración. Funciono todo a la perfección, Dios te bendice.
